# How can I change mutable incremental number to be functional

Tags: scala

I have this code UniqueKeyGenerator, there is a mutable variable number to be incrementally added, because I want to make the generated value to be predictable, I wonder how can I change it to be value instead of variable

```
object UniqueKeyGenerator {

  var number = 0

  def generate(suiteClass: Class[_]): String = {
    number = number + 1
    suiteClass.getCanonicalName + "." + this.number
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to express this with a `val` instead of a `var`, you could use an `Iterator`.

```
object UniqueKeyGenerator {
  val numbers = Iterator.iterate(0)(_ + 1)
  def generate(suiteClass: Class[_]): String =
    s"${suiteClass.getCanonicalName}.${numbers.next()}"
}
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking - maybe provide some more context?

If you have all of the inputs up front, then you can write something like this:

```
Seq(classOf[String], classOf[Int], classOf[String]).zipWithIndex
  .map({ case (suiteClass, i) => s"${suiteClass.getCanonicalName}.$i" })

// res: List(java.lang.String.0, int.1, java.lang.String.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from an Iterator you can also use a closure, for example if the id you want to generate is not just the next natural number, but a result of a more complex expression.

```
val nextId = {
    var id = 0
    () => {
        id = id + 1 // change it to something more complex if you like
        id
    }
}
```

The "id" here is still a variable, but it is not accessible from the outside. The only way you can use it is by calling nextId:

```
def generate(suiteClass: Class[_]): String = {
    suiteClass.getCanonicalName + "." + nextId()
}
```